# Cardano-Node 1.35.0 Build Error on M1 Mac

Tags: cardano-node, install, m1

I'm trying to install cardano-node version 1.35.0 on my M1 Mac.  It worked (somewhat) previously with version 1.34.2 using LLVM.  Currently I am running into this error when it tries to build threepenny-gui:

```
dlopen(/Users/stefan/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.7/lib/libHSHsOpnSSL-0.11.7.2-e201b3b3-ghc8.10.7.dylib, 0x0005): symbol not found in flat namespace (_DSA_free)
```

It looks like the issue is with the openSSL library with cabal is missing a required symbol.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this available?

Comment: This might be answered in https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8803/cardano-node-and-cli-install-llvm-error .

Comment: @ErikdeCastroLopo, that didn't address my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had to do with the openSSL library I was using and was resolved in the instructions provided here: https://github.com/mallapurbharat/cardano-tx-sample/blob/main/0_installation/Old/macos_m1_process.md

This included including the homebrew openssl library.  Specifically [here](https://github.com/mallapurbharat/cardano-tx-sample/blob/main/0_installation/Old/macos_m1_process.md#edit-bashrc--zshrc-and-input-the-below-lines) and [here](https://github.com/mallapurbharat/cardano-tx-sample/blob/main/0_installation/Old/macos_m1_process.md#in-case-you-face-any-issues--errors-regarding-hsopenssl-add-the-below-lines-to-the-cabalproject-file-under-cardano-node-folder).